# CSS :first-letter gets cut off at the border of the paragraph

Tags: css, firefox, webkit, typography

I have a problem with my drop caps. Please take a look at this page http://www.madebypaz.com/portfolio/interaction/user-centred-design

The :first-letter gets cut off at the top in webkit, Firefox pushes it down a line. Can you give some advice how to fix this so it only spans across two lines and doesn't get cut off at the top?

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this rule:

```
.single-item .post-body p + p + p::first-letter,
article.blog .single-item.text p + p::first-letter { ... }
```

The problematical properties are line-height and height. I have found that these values work:

```
line-height: 1em;
height: 0.7em;
```

However, this will cause it to span 3 lines...

Comment: thanks! Is there a way to somehow push the first-letter up so it only spans 2 lines? I tried display:block and then positioning it, but that didn't work at all. What's odd is that the same CSS works perfectly on this page: http://blog.paznow.com. I tried everything but I can't figure out what is causing the clipping on the other pages.

Comment: @Paz Inspect that paragraph in Chrome's developer tools and analyze its computed style.